# How can I do to optimize my code using dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code :

```
a = ""
b = ""
if a == "Hello":
    b = "Hi"
elif a == "Bye":
    b = "Good Bye"
```

I thought to use something like that :

```
mydict = {"Hello": "Hi", "Bye": "Good Bye"}
```

and use a lambda function which consist in looking at the keys of mydict and apply the value in function of the value of the variable a.

Di you have others ideas ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: No need to write a lambda. You can simply do `b = mydict[a]`

Comment: Don't think you even need a lambda -- just do `b = mydict[a]` in a try/except.

Comment: Why would you use a lambda function?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You've got the idea. Try this.

```
mydict = {"Hello": "Hi", "Bye": "Good Bye"}
print(mydict.get(input('Greet: ')))
```

No need for lambda.

Comment: @Tom note the likely important use of `mydict.get()` rather than `mydict[]`